# Can PEP proxy discriminate entities?

Tags: fiware

Can PEP proxy (working with Idm Keyrock) allow access to only some entities of Orion?

Example Scenario:

1. There are 2 types of entities on Orion classified by Entity_Type:

   - `Kitchen` and `Bathroom`
2. User `Plumber` only can modify/comsume `Bathroom` type entities.
3. User `Cook` only can create/comsume to `Kitchen` type entities.
4. User `Admin` can modify/create/comsume to **all** entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, neither the reference implementation of the PEP Proxy (Wilma) or TI+D's version (Steelskin) offer that functionality (though it was suggested more than once).

Using standard NGSI operations (updateContext and queryContext), it would be hard to implement in Wilma (I think) and would require to modify Orion's plugins in Steelskin. The only piece missing to have support to fine grained security is (in the Steelskin case) to add the entity information to the FRN used for security.

But if you restrict yourself to convenience operations (that reflect their Ids and attributes in the URL), you could use the security over REST resources to restrict the resources based on some entity features (but this would probably imply some work with XACML and so). In this case, probably both PEP proxies could be used.

**EDIT:** [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4m624nmO3jRjNalGE11lFLQixnfCENMV6dc54wUCCg/edit#gid=0) you can find the complete set of convenience operations, where you can find what information can be added to the URL for the creation of security rules.